# How can I set up RNG Conflict with a multi day event

Tags: 8, rng

I'm loving the [RNG](https://drupal.org/project/rng) module and the conflict functionality, but I'm a little confused regarding how to set up my seminars and events.

My current use case is I have a simple four-day event with one optional seminar every day.

Initially, I created one registration type "spring seminars", and one event type "Registration". Then I created the four seminars as content, and couldn't figure out how to allow people to register for more than one, as conflict made the other three days unavailable as soon as a registrant registered for one day.

Then I went back and created four different event types, "spring seminar day 1, spring seminar day 2, etc." Then I recreated the four seminars, one per event type, and it allows registrants to register separately. This allowed registrants to register for more than one, but doesn't allow me to keep all sessions under the same seminar [event type] and doesn't work well with calendar if I decide to have more than one seminar per event per day [when I would like to keep them all under the same event type]. It also seems like I was missing a simple "no conflict" option when all four seminars were under the same event type.

Here's the basic layout of the two seminar [registration type?] & session [event?] types the Kobe Education Commission puts on;

- 3-5 day seminar > 1 timeslot per day > 1 session per timeslot
  Registrants can register for any of the events as there is no conflict with either timing or with having specific topics for different groups of registrants. I'd like these to be the same registration type "spring seminar" if possible.
- 1 day seminar > 5 timeslots per day > 3-5 sessions per timeslot
  Registrants can only register for one seminar per timeslot, and there may be specific sessions that a group of registrants isn't eligible for.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! _Best_ is always subjective: What is best for you could not be the best for somebody else. Also, we aren't here to give suggestions, but answer questions with a definitive answer.

Comment: Hi W0LF, trying to clarify some things here. What is your definition of a seminar? Is it a whole day thing or something that can occur multiple times per day, say for ~2hrs at a time. You may also need to rethink your definition of "event". Where normally in day-to-day use an event could be for example "WWDC 2016". Whereas RNG events would be a single timeslot, for example: "UI for beginners". Grouping multiple events into a multi-event encompassing label (such as WWDC) is not handled by RNG.

Comment: It may be worth providing a simplified diagram of your event.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sure - here's a basic diagram of the two seminar [registration type?] & session [event?] types the Kobe Education Commission puts on;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my interpretation of your multi day seminars:

[image: multi day seminar diagram]

I think for your first scenario where there is no conflicting sessions, there is no need to enable [RNG Conflict](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng_conflict).

For the second scenario where you have multiple (3-5) sessions potentially running at the same time. You should have some field on the event nodes that uniquely identify each. You could do this by:

1. Adding a integer field representing the timeslot number (timeslot 1, 2, 3 etc). Or,
2. Add a date field on each event with the start datetime for each session. Then set RNG Conflict to use one of these options.

You may also want to add a field representing the overarching seminar. Resulting in something along the lines of:

[image: seminar event field configuration]
[image: conflicts setting form for seminar event node type]

Your site only needs a single event type (a node type, etc), and a single registration type no matter how many seminars you have. If you are customising your registration form then you may want to add more registration types, but this would be unusual.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed - I will update after trying it all out.

Comment: For the seminar node - entity reference, would that be a content type "seminar" potentially with fields to give general and registration information about the seminar, or something else? Right now I'm understanding it as a content type, that I create welcome pages for the vairous seminars for - such as Spring Seminar, Skills Development Conference, etc. and then having fields for description, duration, participants, sponsors, location, etc.

Comment: @W0LF Right. You could require the user to type in the name of the seminar, or in that use case I have created a new content type called seminar. Those nodes would hold general information about the seminar. If you dont want to expose those seminar nodes to the public that fine. The entity reference field has a nice widget for content editors which reduces any problems that could arise from a regular text field, such as typos. So long as the seminar field has a unique & matching value across your events then RNG Conflict will use that.